# How to hide the source code in Python forever?

Tags: python, locking, pyinstaller

Is there a way how to be sure, my source code is really hidden?
I use pyinstaller to create exe, in order to my friends can use my app without
python. My idea was to create a USB disk with all files from pyinstaller, they are locked to prevent the reading the code. This app could be started only by a shortcut on desktop. But i did not find a way how to solve it. 
Do somebody know a functional way to lock my python app without opportunity of reading the code in order to use it only?

Comment: You can use pyinstaller with `--onefile` option. So, you will have only *exe* file without any additional ones.

Comment: You could look into pyarmor. It obfuscates your code for you. It will make it another step harder. Creating a file with pyinstaller already makes it tough to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Thank you Bogdan. I hope the --onefile is very safely.

Answer (score 2):

You could compile your code into "pyc" format with [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html)

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(filename, compiled_filename, optimize=2)
```

> Note this :
> You need the same version of python and all library that you use to launch this compiled file.
> For load file (e.g. : open("text.txt", "r")), you need to specify all the tree (e.g. : open("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyProgram/test.txt", "r"))